# Option to use URL filename when saving pages in Opera?

Tags: opera

I'm using Opera 12.12 on Win7.  When I save a page, by default the file is named using the title of the web page (as given by the <title> tag).  Often this is what I want, but not always.

By contrast, FireFox by default names the saved file using the file name component of the URL, not the title.  Sometimes this is what I want, sometimes not.

Is there a way in Opera to configure whether the default save file name will come from the title or from the URL?  (I've read FireFox will soon have such an option but I prefer Opera at the moment.)

(I'd actually love for this to be configurable per-site, but I'll keep dreaming).

Comment: You would like to configure this per site... How often are you saving the same site?

Comment: @DaveRook I save on a daily basis from the same _sites_ .. just not the same _pages_.

Comment: Not an answer, but, Firefox has an extension for this: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/title-save/. I don't know Opera, but did you look through the extensions?

Comment: Does this https://addons.opera.com/en/extensions/details/live-page-code/ help?

Comment: @Dave Rook thanks for the tip.  Interesting extension.  Couldn't get it working (even after adding the MIME type) but I'm not sure it changes the save file name anyway.  Searching "save" in Extensions doesn't show anything else of interest.